# make template class with std::vector<T> non-copyable when T is non-copyable

Tags: c++, class-template, copy-assignment

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class V {
public:
    template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_assignable_v<U>, int> = 0>
    auto operator = (const V &rhs) -> V & { v = rhs.v; return *this; }
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

template<typename T>
class U {
public:
    template<typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_assignable_v<U>, int> = 0>
    auto operator = (const U &rhs) -> U & { t = rhs.t; return *this; }
private:
    T t;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<std::unique_ptr<int>>);    // success
    static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<U<std::unique_ptr<int>>>); // success
    static_assert(!std::is_copy_assignable_v<V<std::unique_ptr<int>>>); // fail
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `U<T>` and `V<T>` have assignment operator when `T` is copy-assignable.

However, `static_assert` to check if `V<std::unique_ptr<int>>` is non-copy-assignable fails although similar check for `U<std::unique_ptr<int>>` successes.

Why does the `static_assert` fail for `V<T>` here and how can I fix it?

Comment: The default copy assignment operator is never a template. To disable it based on a template parameter, conditionally inherit from a non-copyable base class

Comment: @Meskton Thank you! Why don't you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special copy assignment operator is never a template.
In [cpp insights](https://cppinsights.io/s/272f1dca) we can see that the compiler will generate a non-template copy assignment operator in addition to the template operator you provided.

You can conditionally disable special member functions of template class based on template parameter by inheriting from a base class with desired semantics

```
#include <type_traits>

class copyable { };
class no_copy_assign { void operator=(const no_copy_assign&) = delete; };

template<class T>
class A :
    std::conditional_t</* Condition */, copyable, no_copy_assign>
{ };
// Condition can be std::is_copy_assignable_v<T>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since C++20 this can be done simpler than using a conditional base, instead using a `requires` clause to enable/disable the default implementation of the copy assignment:

```
template<typename T>
class V {
public:
    V(const V&) requires std::is_copy_constructible_v<T> = default;
    V(V&&) = default;

    auto operator=(const V&) -> V& requires std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> = default;
    auto operator=(V&&) -> V& = default;
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};
```

Although I think you really want `(std::is_copy_assignable_v<T> && std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>)` because the copy assignment of `std::vector<T>` may be using either. Or even better `std::copyable<T>` which is a concept that additionally verifies some details that are required by the containers, e.g. that the copy assignment returns `T&` and so on.

Comment: Or even std::copyable...

Comment: @JeffGarrett Yes true. Just `std::is_copy_assignable_v` and `std::is_copy_constructible_v` is not enough to satisfy [_CopyAssignable_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) which is what the containers use as a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it, with a constexpr function to evaluate copyable conditions. Compile time test code attached.

```
#include <type_traits>

class copyable
{
};

class non_copyable
{
public:
    non_copyable(const non_copyable&) = delete;
    non_copyable& operator=(const non_copyable&) = delete;
};

template<typename type_t>
constexpr bool is_copyable()
{
    return
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<type_t> &&
        std::is_copy_assignable_v<type_t>;
}


template<typename type_t>
class my_class_t :
    public std::conditional_t<is_copyable<type_t>(), copyable, non_copyable>
{
};

class test
{
public:
    test() = default;
    ~test() = default;
    test(const test&) = delete;
    test& operator=(const test&) = delete;
};


int main()
{
    static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<test>);
    static_assert(!std::is_copy_constructible_v<my_class_t<test>>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inheriting from `copyable` or `on_copyable` should be private. There is no reason that these base classes should be visible to users of `my_class_t`.

Comment: @Mestkon fair points :)